# Loading json created in in fabricjs 1.7 to a canvas of version 3.4.0 gives type error

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to load a json object (created using fabricjs version 1.7)
in the the fabric version 3.4 using loadFromJson method. I am getting following error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromObject' of undefined

But if I load it using version 1.7 it works fine. Actually I am migrating my project from Version 1.7 to 3.4.0 version of fabric.

Comment: For which object it gives error? can you reproduce it on snippet/fiddle?

Comment: I am getting this error

fabric.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromObject' of undefined
    at fabric.min.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.enlivenObjects (fabric.min.js:1)
    at i._enlivenObjects (fabric.min.js:1)
    at i.loadFromJSON (fabric.min.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index2.php:46)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Use debug build of fabricjs, not minified, put a breakpoint and check for which object it gives error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see from your question on [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/smGlKMrZ5tc), the class `fabric.PathGroup` is removed after v2.0, which gives type error.

You can find about this more in [v2-breaking-changes](http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes) and follow the given instruction.

Comment: Many thanks for your support sir. This trick works perfectly fine. :-)